# Get Link to Feed On Term or Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, links, rss, feed

Instead of building the link myself, I was wondering if wordpress has a function which generates a link to a given feed, be it a taxonomy, term, or post type. Perhaps it might even generate the little feed icon.

Before building it myself, it occurred to me they probably have a function. But my research turns up nothing.

Answer (score 2):

For **terms and taxonomies** use `get_term_feed_link`:

> "Returns a link to the feed for all posts in a given term. A specific
>   feed can be requested or left blank to get the default feed."

See also `get_tag_feed_link` and `get_category_feed_link`.

For **post types** see `get_post_type_archive_feed_link`.

These functions are located in in [wp-includes/link-template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L0).